# react-big-calendar How to update SASS variables?

Tags: react-big-calendar

I need to style react-big-calendar as per my application styling. This can be achieved by writing custom css classes and importing them. But I am wondering if there is any way to change SCSS variables. 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

RBC provides SCSS for you to use in compiling your own CSS, overriding any of it's `variables` with your own. In your own SCSS file:

```
@import '~react-big-calendar/lib/sass/styles';
// your override variables and classes
```